# Alter a module's setting

Tags: 7

I am using the [Entity background](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_background) module, which at the start of [its .module file](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/entity_background/-/blob/7.x-1.x/module/entity_background_image/entity_background_image.module#L11) has a line which defines an image style constant.

```php
define('EB_IMAGE_STYLE', 'large');
```

I don't want to use that image style, and I don't want to alter the original .module file.

I thought I could write a tiny module just to redefine that line, to alter it. After hours of trying to search for and understand hooks, I am no closer to a solution.

How can I correctly achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to programmatically alter it, as there is a configuration form that allows you to change it, the [README.txt](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/entity_background/-/blob/7.x-1.x/module/entity_background_image/README.txt) says

> The image style used for the background image can be changed by going
> to "admin/config/system/entity_background_image"

There is also a link to it in configuration

[image]

[image]